# How to translate into Esperanto the movement Foodsharing or Disco Soup

Tags: translation, food

I do live in Germany where the **Foodsharing**.de movement is quite strong, the goal is to fight everyday food waste and to raise awareness about this problem in society,

It also exists events named **Disco Soup** where they gather and cook all the big remaining from a food pickup in a day and cook to conscience people and spread the values of reduce our waste and consumerism.

How to translate both terms into Esperanto and for the Esperanto community? This name will be used to create FB groups and translate websites related to that movement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ĉar ni bezonas mallongan, fortan esprimon, mi proponas la vorton „Manĝodivido”. Ne necesas uzi la pli longan radikon *manĝaĵ-* ĉar *manĝo* jam signifas la tuton de la nutraĵoj, konsumataj dum manĝo (vidu http://vortaro.net/#man%C4%9Do).

Por la dua nocio mi simple proponas „diskosupo”. La termino jam estas sufiĉe internacia, kaj ĝi ne signifas, ke la supo estas farita el diskoj, same kiel vaportrajno ne estas farita el vaporo. Ĝi povas simple signifi supon, aŭ iun ajn miksmanĝaĵon, kiun oni konsumas dum iu ludas diskojn.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for something like ‘Manĝaĵokunhavigo’ and ‘Salatsuparo’. The word ‘salato’ can be both a food such as lettuce but also mean “a mess”. If you'd rather not risk having it mixed up with the former you could say something like that ‘Restaĵsuparo’.

Answer (score 0):

Food Sharing = kunhavigo de manĝaĵo = **manĝaĵkunhavigo**.

Disco Soup = granda kunkuirado.

Answer (score 0):

Food Sharing = Manĝdividi.  Mi preferas la hispana kaj la franca en ekspresi "Share"- compartir en la hispana, kaj partager en la franca.  "Share" en la angla havas aliajn signifojn.

Disco Soup = Manĝdividi kunkuirado. Tiu ĉi vorto kaptas la signifo de dividi manĝo kaj kuiri ĝin kune.